# Ignore file causing Eslint errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I inherited a typescript React project. In `package.json` there is this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start:dev": "env-cmd -f .env.development react-scripts start",
  },
```

I run the project with: `yarn run start:dev`

Im getting errors:

```
src/services/FCSServices/fcsTransformer/logicle.js
  Line 81:3:    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 83:3:    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 83:20:   'M' is not defined                                                     no-undef
  Line 83:31:   'A' is not defined                                                     no-undef
  Line 83:40:   'W' is not defined                                                     no-undef
  Line 85:13:   'M' is not defined                                                     no-undef
  Line 85:17:   'A' is not defined                                                     no-undef
  Line 86:12:   'W' is not defined                                                     no-undef
  Line 86:17:   'M' is not defined                                                     no-undef
  Line 86:21:   'A' is not defined                                                     no-undef
  Line 88:13:   'A' is not defined                                                     no-undef
  Line 88:18:   'M' is not defined                                                     no-undef
  Line 88:22:   'A' is not defined                                                     no-undef
  Line 307:10:  'slope' is not defined                                                 no-undef
  Line 307:21:  'slope' is not defined                                                 no-undef
  Line 317:11:  'M' is not defined                                                     no-undef
  Line 317:19:  'W' is not defined                                                     no-undef
  Line 351:1:   'calculateW' is not defined                                            no-undef
  Line 367:1:   'getTMWA' is not defined                                               no-undef
```

I want Eslint to ignore this file during, so I added an `excludes` property to `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["src/services/FCSServices/fcsTransformer/*"]
}
```

However when I run again with `yarn run start:dev` I still see the same build errors. How can I ignore this file?

Comment: Did you try just "exclude": ["src/services/FCSServices/fcsTransformer"] without *?

Comment: Yes, same issue